Read-only class attributes that pass type checking, the modern way (3.11+)
Relevant older questions:

Class properties in Python 3.11+
What are some similar alternatives to using classmethod and property decorators together?

Out of all of them, the following answer was most appealing to me. A small rewrite + example (I am using Python 3.12+):
from functools import update_wrapper
from typing import Callable


class classprop[T]:
    def __init__(self, method: Callable[..., T]):
        self.method = method
        update_wrapper(self, method)

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None) -> T:
        if cls is None:
            cls = type(obj)
        return self.method(cls)


class MyClass:
    @classprop
    def hello(self) -> str:
        return "world"


x = MyClass()
x.hello

This raises a type error (silenced in the original answer):
Argument of type "Self@classprop[T@classprop]" cannot be assigned to 
parameter "wrapper" of type "(**_PWrapper@update_wrapper) -> _RWrapper@update_wrapper" 
in function "update_wrapper"
  Type "Self@classprop[T@classprop]" is incompatible with 
  type "(**_PWrapper@update_wrapper) -> _RWrapper@update_wrapper"

Is there a way to address this type error, instead of silencing it? (i.e. is it raising a valid concern?) What is the error even saying?

why are you using update_wrapper?

Explanation
functools.update_wrapper() expects a Callable as the first argument, so the type checkers are making no mistakes.
update_wrapper() is supposed to make the wrapper look and behave (at runtime) the same as the wrapped by assigning/updating some attributes. A wrapper should therefore be callable, but your classprop isn't, even though it happens to work on classprop instances in this case.
Silencing the type checker is a valid choice here, at least if you have no intention to write something like this:
@classprop
def foo() -> int:
    return 42

foo()  # fail at runtime

Option 1: The compromise
As a compromise, you can also make classprop instances callable only at type-checking time:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
class classprop[T]:
    ...

    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        def __call__(self) -> T:
            ...

Option 2: Doing it right
Doing it the right way requires specifying the type arguments, so if you are into strict mode:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
class classprop[O, T]:
    method: Callable[[type[O]], T]

    # `Any` is actually supposed to be `type[O]`.
    # However, type checkers won't be able to figure out
    # that `cls` is `type[O]` and not `O`.
    def __init__(self, method: Callable[[Any], T]):
        self.method = method
        update_wrapper(self, method)

    def __get__(self, obj: O | None, cls: type[O] | None = None) -> T:
        ...
    
    def __call__(self, instance: O) -> T:
        return self.__get__(instance)

class MyClass:
    @classprop['MyClass', str]
    def hello(self) -> str:
        return "world"

Option 3: If the property will never refer to cls
If you don't care about the class at all (i.e. the property in question has no use for it), things get a bit simpler:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
class classprop[T]:
    method: Callable[[], T]

    def __init__(self, method: Callable[[], T]):
        self.method = method
        update_wrapper(self, method)

    def __get__(self, obj: Any, cls: type[Any] | None = None) -> T:
        return self.method()
    
    def __call__(self, instance: Any) -> T:
        return self.method()

class MyClass:
    @classprop
    def hello() -> str:  # mypy complains about this
        return "world"


Should the __get__ method in Option 2 (I added some headers to help organize your answer so that we can talk about specific parts of it) have a body that is also return self.method()? Currently it is just ...

@bzm3r I didn't want to clutter the snippet, so I used .... It should be trivial to fill that part in, no?
